# Iterating Over Array Literal

Tags: dust.js

Is it possible in dust to iterate over an array literal?

If I had JSON with like so `{arr: ["a", "b", "c"]}` I would do:

```
{#arr}
....
{/arr}
```

Is there a way to do this with an array I define in the dust template? Perhaps something like:

```
{#["a", "b", "c"]}
{/?}
```

I know that's not correct syntax, but hopefully it illustrates what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Dust doesn't include this language functionality natively. That's why you can write **helpers** in your context or as global functions to add new features to Dust.

Here's a basic helper that iterates over a list of items. There's no error checking or anything, but it's a starting point.

```
dust.helpers.iterate = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  var items = params.items.split(',');
  return chunk.section(items, context, bodies, params);
}
```

Then, use it in your template:

```
{@iterate items="ab,cd,ef,12"}
  Item: {.}{~n}
{/iterate}
```

If you are using this in a single context, you can place helpers directly into your Dust context as well, and invoke them like `{#iterate}`.